# Silently Install APK in Android Programmatically

Tags: android, installation, apk, silent-installer

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                File path = context.getFilesDir();
                File outputFile = new File(path, fileName + ".apk");
                int repetition = 1;
                while (outputFile.exists()) {
                    outputFile = new File(path, fileName + " (+" + repetition + ").apk");
                    repetition++;
                }

                if (!path.exists()) {
                    path.mkdirs();
                }

                URL url = new URL(downloadUrl);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = c.getInputStream();
                float totalSize = (float) c.getContentLength();

                Pair<Integer, InputStream> bitmapToStream = Pair.create((int) totalSize, inputStream);
                InputStream in = bitmapToStream.second;
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                long fileSize = bitmapToStream.first;
                byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fileSize];
                int len;
                float per;
                float downloaded = 0f;

                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
                    out.write(buf,0,len);
                    downloaded += len;
                    per = (downloaded * 100 / totalSize);
                    publishProgress((int) per);
                }

                out.close();
                in.close();

                installAPK(path, outputFile.getName());
                updatePatchListener.onDone();

//                openNewVersion(outputFile.getPath());
                return true;
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                this.exception = exception;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private void installAPK(File path, String apkName) {
            try {
                Process p = new ProcessBuilder("pm install -r " + apkName).directory(path).start();
                p.waitFor();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I want to install the apk that I have downloaded silently, but always get the error permission denied..

I already use command **pm install** or **adb install** or **adb shell** or **run-as**, but all not working for me. Always permission denied

is there any solution for me..?

```
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pm install -r Update (+3).apk" (in directory "/data/user/0/com.c.aka/files"): error=13, Permission denied
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at com.c.cpayid.UpdatePatch$DownloadNewVersion.installAPK(UpdatePatch.java:129)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at com.c.cpayid.UpdatePatch$DownloadNewVersion.doInBackground(UpdatePatch.java:115)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at com.c.cpayid.UpdatePatch$DownloadNewVersion.doInBackground(UpdatePatch.java:54)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
```

2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:133)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:132)
2023-01-15 14:14:21.787 12507-12558/com.c.aka W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)

this error show

Answer (score 3):

You cannot install an APK silently.  Imagine if any piece of malware could download an APK and install it to hide itself and include additional pieces of malware on a device.  That would be bad.  That's why no app can install others without the user intervening.

If you're the device owner and trying to install apps across your fleet, look at Android Enterprise.  That can install apps.  But there's no way to do it programatically.

Comment: `no app can install others without the user intervening` I would limit this to user apps because system apps like those from manufacturer and some Google apps like PlayStore have system permissions and can install apps without user consent.